# How to make MongoDB Service Available?

Tags: java, mongodb, osgi-bundle, bndtools, amdatu

I am developing OSGi Mongodb bundle I have also added the following dependencies

1. com.mongodb
2. org.apache.felix.fileinstal
3. org.amdatu.mongo
4. org.apache.felix.configadmin

and all the dependency managers but in gogo console I get the following error message

```
org.amdatu.mongo
org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory(service.pid=org.amdatu.mongo) registered
org.osgi.service.log.LogService service optional unavailable
[11] agenda.mongodb.mongo_gfs
agenda.mongo.inter.AgendaMongo() unregistered
org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService service required unavailable
```

the main problem is **MongoDBService is not available** I must require this service for solving this problem I have read the book according to them

> From a development perspective, everything seems fine, but when you
>   run the appli‐ cation, it will complain that the MongoDBService is
>   unavailable. You can figure this out with the dmcommand in the shell.
>   We did however set up MongoDB on our system and deployed the necessary
>   dependencies in our runtime. Still, the  MongoDBService  was unable to
>   start. How come? This is because the  MongoDBService  needs some
>   mandatory configuration in order to know to what database to connect
>   to. The Amdatu MongoDB Serviceuses the Managed Service Factory pattern
>   (see  Chapter 4), and in order to bootstrap it, we need to supply a
>   configuration file. In order to supply the configuration file, we need
>   to create a new folder in our  agendaproject. Create a new folder
>   called load. This is the default name that the runtime will look for
>   in order to spot configuration files. Next, add an empty text file and
>   call it something like  org.amdatu.mongo-demo.xml. The configuration
>   file needs at least the following information: *dbName=demo*

I have also apply this but its still unavailable.

This is interface:

```
package agenda.mongo.inter;
import java.io.InputStream;

public interface AgendaMongo {
   public String store_in_db();
   public InputStream getData(Object file_id);
}
```

This is the implementation for Mongodb:

```
package agenda.mongodb.gridfs;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import agenda.mongo.inter.AgendaMongo;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFS;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSDBFile;
import com.mongodb.gridfs.GridFSInputFile;

    public class Gridfs_Mongodb implements AgendaMongo{
        GridFSInputFile gfsinput=null;
        private volatile MongoDBService mongoservice;
        public String store_in_db() {

        /*try {
            GridFS gfsHandler;
            gfsHandler = new GridFS(mongoservice.getDB(), "rest_data");// database
            File uri = new File("f:\\get1.jpg");                                    // name and
            gfsinput = gfsHandler.createFile(uri);
            gfsinput.saveChunks(1000);
            gfsinput.setFilename("new file");
            gfsinput.save();
            //System.out.println(gfsinput.getId());
            //save_filepath("file",gfsinput.getId());
            Object get_id = gfsinput.getId();//get_filename();
            //System.out.println(getData(get_id));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }*/
        System.out.println("DB:" + mongoservice.getDB());
        return mongoservice.getDB()+"";
    }

    /*
     * Retrieving the file
     */
    public InputStream getData(Object file_id) {
        GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(mongoservice.getDB(), "rest_data");
        GridFSDBFile dataOutput = gfsPhoto.findOne((ObjectId) file_id);
        DBCursor cursor = gfsPhoto.getFileList();
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
        System.out.println(dataOutput);
        return dataOutput.getInputStream();

    }
    void start(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(store_in_db());
    }


}
```

Here I was just trying to get database name because every thing can be done after that but I t was returning me NULL because `MongoDBService` is Unavailable.

At this is `Activator` class

```
package agenda.mongodb.gridfs;

import org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import agenda.mongo.inter.AgendaMongo;

public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase {

    @Override
    public void init(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager manager)
            throws Exception {
        manager.add(createComponent()
                .setInterface(AgendaMongo.class.getName(), null)
                .setImplementation(Gridfs_Mongodb.class)
                .add(createServiceDependency()
                .setService(MongoDBService.class)
                .setRequired(true)));
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager arg1)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

The Interface package is an exported package and the implementation package is private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file should have a .cfg extension (not .xml).

Comment: I have try it but no affect :(

Comment: So, step by step you need to debug it then. That is what file install should pick up. So first step is to make sure it does. Does the configuration end up in Configuration Admin? Does it work if you programmatically put that configuration there? You're on the right path but without sharing your actual code/project it's hard to keep guessing. :)

Comment: I have not added any MetaType because I don't think we required it.

Comment: Your code looks okay. If the MongoDBService does not appear, somehow your configuration is not working, which brings me back to my comment above about making sure that your configuration a) ends up in ConfigurationAdmin and b) is sent to the Amdatu Mongo bundle.

Comment: You are Rights but I think I my configurations are correct. How can I test them need help ??

Comment: See above, write some code to see if the configuration reaches the ConfigurationAdmin service.